GCP Dataflow: Module not found error when running dataflow flex template
I am getting a recurring error with missing deps (some variation of Module not found) when I try to run a dataflow template.
My Python project uses poetry for setting up the env and dependency management. I initially used poetry install to install all the deps on the docker image I am using in the Dataflow template:
FROM gcr.io/dataflow-templates-base/python311-template-launcher-base:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6 -y

ARG PYTHON_FILE
ARG METADATA_FILE

ENV POETRY_NO_INTERACTION=1 \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=1 \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_CREATE=1 \
    POETRY_HOME="/opt/poetry" \
    POETRY_CACHE_DIR=/tmp/poetry_cache \
    FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_FILE=$PYTHON_FILE

RUN curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH="$POETRY_HOME/bin:/app/.venv/bin:$PATH"

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock $METADATA_FILE ./

RUN poetry install --without dev --no-root && rm -rf $POETRY_CACHE_DIR

COPY src ./src

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/google/dataflow/python_template_launcher"]

But I was getting the aforementioned error, so I did an export of the deps into a requirements.txt file and used that in combination with pip instead, in my Dockerfile:
FROM gcr.io/dataflow-templates-base/python311-template-launcher-base:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6 -y

ARG PYTHON_FILE
ARG METADATA_FILE
ARG WORKDIR=/app

ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_FILE=$PYTHON_FILE \
    FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE="${WORKDIR}/requirements.txt" \
    PIP_NO_DEPS=1

WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}

COPY requirements.txt $METADATA_FILE ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir -r $FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE \
    && pip download --no-cache-dir --dest /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache -r $FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE

COPY src ./src

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/google/dataflow/python_template_launcher"]

However I am still getting this error (with the opencv-python package) when the Apache Beam Python worker executes:
Could not load main session. Inspect which external dependencies are used in the main module of your pipeline. Verify that corresponding packages are installed in the pipeline runtime environment and their installed versions match the versions used in pipeline submission environment. For more information, see: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker_main.py", line 115, in create_harness
    _load_main_session(semi_persistent_directory)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker_main.py", line 354, in _load_main_session
    pickler.load_session(session_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 65, in load_session
    return desired_pickle_lib.load_session(file_path)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/dill_pickler.py", line 446, in load_session
    return dill.load_session(file_path)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 368, in load_session
    module = unpickler.load()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 472, in load
    obj = StockUnpickler.load(self)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 826, in _import_module
    return __import__(import_name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/apache/beam-venv/beam-venv-worker-sdk-0-0/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "/opt/apache/beam-venv/beam-venv-worker-sdk-0-0/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 153, in bootstrap
    native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2")
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I am building my dataflow template using this command (the substitued vars are not relevant I don't think?):
gcloud dataflow flex-template build $(TEMPLATE_PATH) \
      --image "$(TEMPLATE_IMAGE)" \
      --sdk-language "PYTHON" \
      --metadata-file "$(METADATA_FILE)"

And I've checked the docker images in the Google Artifact Registry.
I've also tried moving the relevant imports into the actual DoFn themselves, per some discussions I had found around save_main_session, but that simply moved the error further downstream.

I'm also trying to solve an error similar to this. Did you find something new?
